# Need to display activity according to TAB selected

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I will try to explain my problem as brief as possible. I have 4 tabs, "Month" "Week" "Day" "Today". Each of these days are a separate activity. When a user clicks "Today" tab, the activity must first check the previous activity, and then accordingly show the current date. For eg. If user has clicked DAY before and then clicks TODAY, the TODAY activity should display today's date. Same goes for both "Month" "Week" activity. The today will check the previous activity and show the current month and current week respectively.

[image: The TABs: each are a separate activity]

Here is the code I have used to make my Tabs.

```
public class Secondactivity extends TabActivity {    
     private TabHost mTabHost;
     private void setupTabHost() {
         mTabHost = getTabHost();
     }
     setupTabHost();
     mTabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(se.copernicus.activity.R.drawable.tab_divider);
     setupTab(new TextView(this), getString(R.string.month));
     setupTab(new TextView(this), getString(R.string.week));
     setupTab(new TextView(this), getString(R.string.day));
     setupTab(new TextView(this), getString(R.string.today));
     mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(getString(R.string.month));

     private void setupTab(final View view, final String tag) {
         View tabview = createTabView(mTabHost.getContext(), tag);
         if (tag.compareTo(getString(R.string.month)) == 0) {
              Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MonthActivity.class);
              TabSpec setContent = mTabHost.newTabSpec(getString(R.string.month)).
              setIndicator(tabview).setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {
                   public View createTabContent(String tag) {
                        return view;
                   }
              });
              setContent.setContent(intent);
              mTabHost.addTab(setContent);
         }
         if (tag.compareTo(getString(R.string.week)) == 0) {
              Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WeekActivity.class);
              TabSpec setContent = mTabHost.newTabSpec(getString(R.string.week)).
              setIndicator(tabview).setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {
                   public View createTabContent(String tag) {
                        return view;
                   }
              });
              setContent.setContent(intent);
              mTabHost.addTab(setContent);
         }
         if (tag.compareTo(getString(R.string.day)) == 0) {
              Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DayActivity.class);
              TabSpec setContent = mTabHost.newTabSpec(getString(R.string.day)).
              setIndicator(tabview).setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {
                   public View createTabContent(String tag) {
                        return view;
                   }
              });
              setContent.setContent(intent);
              mTabHost.addTab(setContent);
         }
         if (tag.compareTo(getString(R.string.today)) == 0) {
              Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DayActivity.class);
              TabSpec setContent = mTabHost.newTabSpec(getString(R.string.today)).
              setIndicator(tabview).setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {
                   public View createTabContent(String tag) {
                        return view;
                   }
              });
              setContent.setContent(intent);
              mTabHost.addTab(setContent);
         }
     }

     private static View createTabView(final Context context, final String text) {
              View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tabs_bg, null);
              TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabsText);
              tv.setText(text);
              return view;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Vinoth,
       It is better to use shared preference for this .store a value in shared preference when u click on a a tab.
   For example u click on day tab use the below shared pref

```
 getSharedPreferences("Test", 0).edit().putString("Check", "day").commit();
```

and use below preference when click on month tab

```
getSharedPreferences("Test", 0).edit().putString("Check", "month").commit();
```

and use below preference when click on week tab

```
getSharedPreferences("Test", 0).edit().putString("Check", "week").commit();
```

and finally when we click on Today tab get the shared preference value according to that value print the day,month,week.Below code is used to get the shared preference value

```
String check_string= getSharedPreferences("Test", 0).getString("Check","day")
if( check_string.equalsIgnorecase("day")
{
// it is coming from day tab
}
else if ( check_string.equalsIgnorecase("month")
{
//it is coming from month tab
}else if ( check_string.equalsIgnorecase("week")
{
//it is coming from week tab
}
```

Comment: Hi Praveena. Thanks for your reply ! I am testing it now. Will get back to you with the results.